# What's the meaning of "vor" in this sentence?

Tags: translation, preposition, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

The sentences are

> Was haben Sie für morgen **vor**?
>   Für wann haben Sie einen Ausflug **vor**?

English Translation:

> What do you have for tomorrow?
>   When do you have an excursion?

Normally, **vor** means "before, in front of...".
I don't see any meaning of "vor" in these translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb your are looking for is *vorhaben*. Look it up.

Answer (score 2):

"Vor" syntatically belongs to "haben",being part of the German word "vorhaben", which can be translated to "to intend", "to mean" or "to plan".

The sentences you gave for an example best translates to

> "What are you planing for tomorrow?".
>
> "When do you plan to have an excursion?"

So, "vor" does not need to be translated separately and does not have any time defining relevance here.